# Determine the amount of splits in a decision tree of sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I developed a decision tree (ensemble) in Matlab by using the "fitctree"-function (link: https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationtree-class.html).

Now I want to rebuild the same ensemble in python. Therefor I am using the sklearn library with the "DecisionTreeClassifier" (link: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html).

In Matlab I defined the maximum amount of splits in each tree by setting:
'MaxNumSplits' — Maximal number of decision splits in the "fitctree"-function.
So with this the amount of branch nodes can be defined.

Now as I understand the attributes of the "DecisionTreeClassifier" object, there isn't any option like this. Am I right? All I found to control the amount of nodes in each tree is the "max_leaf_nodes" which obviously controls the number of leaf nodes.

And secondly: What does "max_depth" exactly control? If it's not "None" what does the integer "max_depth = int" stand for?

I appreciate your help and suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far I know there is no option to limit the total number of splits (nodes) in scikit-learn. However, you can set `max_leaf_nodes` to `MaxNumSplits + 1` and the result should be equivalent.

Assume our tree has `n_split` split nodes and `n_leaf` leaf nodes. If we split a leaf node, we turn it into a split node and add two new leaf nodes. So `n_splits` and `n_leafs` both increase by 1. We usually start with only the root node (`n_splits=0`, `n_leafs=1`) and every splits increases both numbers. In consequence, the number of leaf nodes is always `n_leafs == n_splits + 1`.

As for `max_depth`; the depth is how many "layers" the tree has. In other words, the depth is the maximum number of nodes between the root and the furthest leaf node. The `max_depth` parameter restricts this depth. It prevents further splitting of a node if it is too far down the tree. (You can think of `max_depth` as a limiting to the number of splits before a decision is made.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your explanation seems logical to me. I tried it. However I am not reaching the same decision tree ensemble as I developed in matlab. This is surely influenced by some other little differences between the two IDEs. But it's ok. I'm not wasting time on creating the exact same classifier as in Matlab. ;)